# How to load a URL which is blocked in our country without VPN?

Tags: android, android-webview, vpn

`Webview` not loading `URL` or website because that website is blocked in our country if we use 3rd party vpn then it will load. is there any way to open url without VPN ?
or is it possible to redirect the url from proxy server online just like many free proxy availble but the problem is that session expire of that link.

Answer (score 0):

If your country has blocked the URL, then you can't access the url without `VPN`. You can create a VPN server`with`openvpn`, then your application can connect to your VPN server. In this way, you can access the URL that is blocked with your application.